# htaccess for ip and referrer

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my development server the, the referrer name will look like `dev.host.in` and the ip will look like `123.456.456.111/dev/`

When I access the site through the ip address, the site is not getting display normally because the css file path is wrong in this case.

How to set a `.htaccess` file to incorporate this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an htaccess to do something like that. Add `<base href="base url">` to your html file.